# Loading a record with the primary key in the url?

Tags: php, mysql, get

is it possible to use GET or something like this to load a record into a form ?.

E.g I have for formA where it has a foreach list of all the clients in the DB , at the end of each row I have a link which is called 'edit' , this link goes to formB.php and is set out like this >>

```
sitename.com/FormB.php?token=<?php echo $ID ?>
```

This gives you an url that looks like the following :

```
http://www.sitename.com/formB.php?token=25
```

The link above would for example load the record with ID 25 into the second form.

I am not sure how to handle the link in the second form though, can you echo GET ID in the second form, or would it have to be GET token ?.

Comment: Did you even read the [doc](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, there's the predefined `$_GET` variable. This is basically an array holding all `GET` paremeters:

```
// url = index.php?foo=bar&hello=world

echo $_GET['foo']; // bar
echo $_GET['hello']; // world
```

So, considering your url and query:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `token`=' . $_GET['token'];
```

To avoid security exploits, we need to use the function `mysql_real_escape_string` around the user-defined parameter when using strings. When using other types such as numbers you can just parse it to a number.

```
// if token is a number
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `token`=' . intval($_GET['token']);

// if token is a string
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `token`=' . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['token']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access your GET-Parameter with the `$_GET`-array. To see whats in there you can use:
`print_r($_GET);`

In the second case you would have to use `$_GET['token']` as the parameter is named `token`.

Note: If you are passing the parameter into a SQL-Query make sure it is secured. In this case with `intval()`. SQL-Injections are bad.